# Django CookieCutter: django.db.utils.OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Tags: python, django, windows, postgresql

**How to fix the fe_sendauth: no password supplied erorr?**

There's this open-source framework for Django that is production-ready (https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django)

I don't exactly know the cause of the error, but I do have some ideas, and I'm going to list out all the possible things that could have led to that error.

I've followed all steps from this doc (https://cookiecutter-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developing-locally.html)

Here are some of my answers to when I initialised the cookiecutter:

```
version [0.1.0]: 0.1.0
timezone [UTC]: GMT
use_whitenoise [n]: n
use_celery [n]: n
use_mailhog [n]: y
use_sentry [n]: y
use_pycharm [n]: n
windows [n]: y
use_docker [n]: n
use_heroku [n]: n
use_compressor [n]: y
Select postgresql_version:
1 - 13.2
2 - 12.6
3 - 11.11
4 - 10.16
Choose from 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 [1]: 1
Select js_task_runner:
1 - None
2 - Gulp
Choose from 1, 2 [1]: 1
Select cloud_provider:
1 - AWS
2 - GCP
3 - None
Choose from 1, 2, 3 [1]: 1
custom_bootstrap_compilation [n]: n
Select open_source_license:
1 - MIT
2 - BSD
3 - GPLv3
4 - Apache Software License 2.0
5 - Not open source
Choose from 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 [1]: 5
keep_local_envs_in_vcs [y]: y
debug[n]: n
```

And then I was at the part where I'm trying to configure the database, and whenever I try to run the `py manage.py migrate` command, an error appears to be this:
`django.db.utils.OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied`

And that error could be caused by a lot factors.

I did this: `createdb -U postgres -W das` which worked because I hopped on pgAdmin4 and I saw the database das, listed on the UI.

And then I kept following the steps from the docs (https://cookiecutter-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developing-locally.html), and did this command: `export DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:<password>@127.0.0.1:5432/<DB name given to createdb>` Placing the postgres' user password in there, and the db name which was das in there as well.

Problem is, I can't seem to use the command `export` (is it because I'm on windows?) , I searched on google, and they said to instead just use the command `set` for it. I'm not really sure if it worked. So one of the causes of the error could be that I used `set` instead of `export` but then I'm not really sure which command to use anymore? There could be other causes as well, I'm not really sure.

I know that seems a hefty amount of information, hopefully it's understandable. Thank you for your time.

Comment: !!! Finally able to do it! So what you want to do is go on the pgAdmin thing -> Servers -> PostgreSQL 13 -> Databases. Now if you've used "postgres" as your default username or whatsover, you'll see it there. Hover on that and right click and click Create -> Database... then for the name of the database, write the one you put in <DB name given to createdb>. Click enter. Now when you go back to your terminal and do `py manage.py migrate` it should work now! Wohoooooo!!!!!!!!! (It was a very tiring experience so just putting it here in case someone needs it)

Comment: Oh and also, I've changed something in the files of cookiecutter. Go on config then settings then to base.py. Change the DATABASES object to this:

`DATABASES = {
    "default": env.db("DATABASE_URL", default="postgres://postgres:<PASSWORD here >@127.0.0.1:5432/<the databse name here>"),
}`